# Накидывание классов в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, html, css

делаю вручную карусель. По кнопке вперед накидывается класс на следующий элемент, а с текущего снимается. Как можно сделать накидывание класса в обратном порядке, по клику на кнопку назад.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам пример, пометил комментариями, где и что - Надеюсь помог!

```js
 let sliderImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
     arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#arrow-left'),     
     arrowRight = document.querySelector('#arrow-right'),
     current = 0;

//Reset Images to "display: none;"
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImgs.length; i++ ) {
    sliderImgs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//Init Slide
function startSlide() {
  reset()
  sliderImgs[0].style.display = 'block';
}

//show previous
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImgs[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
  current--;
}

//Show Next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImgs[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
  current++;
}

//Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImgs.length;
  }
  
  slideLeft();
})

//right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (current === sliderImgs.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  
  slideRight();
});

//Timed slider
setInterval(function(){
  if (current === sliderImgs.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  
  slideRight();
}, 5000)

startSlide();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, .width #slider, .slide-content {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.slide1 {
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/536');
}

.slide2 {
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/485');
}

.slide3 {
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/919');
}

.slide-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-content span {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

#arrow-left {
  border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent #333 transparent transparent;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#arrow-right {
  border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #444;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#arrow-right:hover {
   border-color: #999 transparent #999 #444;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #999; 
}

#arrow-left:hover {
  border-color: #999 #333 #999 transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #999; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>We are Smooth</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span class="content">We are Cool</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span class="content">We are Awesome</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!